# How to merge two dimensions of a tensor without assuming the shape of it

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

Let's assume the following function:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

def broadcast_sum(a, b):
    a = K.expand_dims(a, 1)
    b = K.expand_dims(b, 2)
    c = a + b
    cs = K.shape(c)
    return K.reshape(c, (cs[0], -1, cs[-1]))
```

Given the two tensors of shapes `(1, 3, 2)` and `(1, 4, 2)`, it correctly returns:

```
>>> broadcast_sum(K.placeholder((1, 3, 2)), K.placeholder((1, 4, 2)))
>>> <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_2:0' shape=(1, 12, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Right now, this function works only with 3D input (because of the `reshape` line). My question is, how can I make this work with any shape (using the same function) without knowing the shape? Of course, I'm assuming the inputs are of the same shape and at least a 3D. But how can I have a single function that works with 3D, 4D and so on?

And I'm assuming that it's always the second dimension (from left) that the function will broadcast and the rest of the dimensions are identical between the two inputs. Here are the shapes that I want to make the same function to work with:

```
>>> broadcast_sum(K.placeholder((1, 3, 5, 2)), K.placeholder((1, 4, 5, 2)))
>>> <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_3:0' shape=(1, 60, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Of course, the returned tensor is wrong right now. It should be of shape `(1, 12, 5, 2)`.

**[UPDATE]**

Please also consider that the first dimension (the batch size) could be `None`. In fact, any of the dimensions except the rightmost one could be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

> And I'm assuming that it's always the second dimension (from left)
>   that the function will broadcast and the rest of the dimensions are
>   identical between the two inputs.

Based on this, I reuse the shape information from one of the inputs.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
def broadcast_sum(a, b):
    final_shape = (a.shape[0], -1, *a.shape[2:])
    a = K.expand_dims(a, 1)
    b = K.expand_dims(b, 2)
    c = a + b
    return K.reshape(c, final_shape)


print(broadcast_sum(K.placeholder((1, 3, 2)), K.placeholder((1, 4, 2))))
print(broadcast_sum(K.placeholder((1, 3, 5, 2)), K.placeholder((1, 4, 5, 2))))

Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(1, 4, 3, 2), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Reshape_1:0", shape=(1, 12, 5, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks, while this helps but I have to insist to use the `K.shape()` since the batch size dimension could be `None`. And if it is, your solution won't work.

Comment: In fact, now that I think of it, any of the dimensions (except the rightmost one) could be `None`. I was hoping I could come up with a solution that relies on manipulating the return value of `K.shape()` so it works all the time (as long as the rightmost dimension is provided).